# Show Text if jquery.validate passes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery.validate.js plugin and everything works fine... however.... I want to show text in a hidden div if the validation passes and the form actually submits.

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
```

how to i modify this line to show "Please Wait While Your Form Submits" in the hiddenmessage div?

```
<div id="hiddenmessage"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) the following should do what you require

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
     $('#hiddenmessage').html('Please Wait While Your Form Submits');
     form.submit();
   }
});
```

Aside: English Written With Every Word Capitalized Looks Weird. Use Proper Formatting Rules For Plain English.